# Javascript URI Malformed

Tags: javascript, web, uri

I have a URI malformed error with this code :

```
URL = www.test.com?au=test&bti=Mon%20p%27tit.

var href = location.href;
href=decodeURIComponent(href.replace(/\+/g," "));
```

Looks like `%27` break everything! And i have no control on those parameters.

Comment: Where are you getting the URI malformed error? Why are you decoding the whole URI?

Comment: And why would `location.href` return an URL like that ?

Comment: Hi everyone. The main objective is to extract information in the URL and display those information for the user. The program is in javascript. Looks like a encoding problem. *ISO and UTF8".